# How to merge two arrays?

Tags: php

After loop made and using following array I can create a new array.

```
$data[$val['gid']][$val['rid']][$val['aid']][$teno][$userid]= array();
```

This results in the array below:

```
array:1 [
  "FS OTHER" => array:1 [
    "FS OTHER" => array:1 [
      "FS OTHER" => array:1 [
        "FS OTHER" => array:1 [
          "D111" => []
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I also have another array:

```
array:41 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "sid" => "D111"
    "desc1" => "BANGKOK"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "sid" => "D111"
    "desc1" => "NONTHABURI"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "sid" => "D112"
    "desc1" => "PATHUM THANI"
  ]
```

Now I need to merge this array based on the 'sid' to get the following result:

```
array:1 [
  "FS OTHER" => array:1 [
    "FS OTHER" => array:1 [
      "FS OTHER" => array:1 [
        "FS OTHER" => array:1 [
          "BANGKOK" => []
          "NONTHABURI"=> []
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Have a look at `array_merge()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php as @treyBake said.

Comment: @treyBake yes but I am not being able to check the last key with another array value

Comment: @SS do you want to merge arrays while creating the 1st array or when it's ready ?

Comment: @splash58 when its ready i guess

Comment: The 1st case it much more easy. if it's available :)

Comment: @splash58 if its easy pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepare another structure of the second array

```
$new = [];
foreach ($arr2 as $x) {
    $new[$x['sid']][$x['desc1']] = [];
}
// [D111 => [ BANGKOK => [], NONTHABURI => [] ],..
```

and then just create the 1st one by:

```
$data[$val['gid']][$val['rid']][$val['aid']][$teno][$userid]= $new[$userid];
```

Comment: $userid is not sure to be available in second array. In that case it gives error

Comment: Have you seen the $new array?

Comment: Are its indexes not the same as $userid in the first?

Comment: According to question above, D111 is available in second array as "sid": D111. But there are some data in first array like D113 which is not available in second array.

Comment: `= isset($new[$userid]) ? $new[$userid] : [];`

Comment: thank you that helped. I was trying to check if value exist in array then make new array :D thank you. you made it simpler